Using Kotlin DTO as @RequestBody in Spring Get Request fail all requests as Bad Request
I have the jackson-kotlin module installed
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-module-kotlin</artifactId>
    <version>2.18.1</version>
</dependency>

and configured
@Configuration
open class JacksonConfig {
    @Bean
    open fun objectMapper(): ObjectMapper {
        return ObjectMapper().registerKotlinModule()
    }
}

However when I try to send a request to this endpoint
@PostMapping("/test")
fun test(@RequestBody promptRequest: PromptRequest): ResponseEntity<String> {
    return ResponseEntity(promptRequest.prompt, HttpStatus.OK)
}

fails with HTTP 400 Bad Request
HTTP/1.1 400 
Vary: Origin
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Method
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Headers
Content-Type: application/problem+json
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Tue, 12 Nov 2024 09:00:56 GMT
Connection: close

{
  "type": "about:blank",
  "title": "Bad Request",
  "status": 400,
  "detail": "Failed to read request",
  "instance": "/test",
  "properties": null
}

when PromptRequest is a Kotlin (data) class:
data class PromptRequest (val prompt: String)

However, when PromptRequest is a Java class, like this:
public class PromptRequest {
    public String prompt;
}

All works fine and I get an HTTP 200 OK:
HTTP/1.1 200 
Vary: Origin
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Method
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Headers
Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 42
Date: Tue, 12 Nov 2024 09:05:08 GMT

input prompt

Response code: 200; Time: 3171ms (3 s 171 ms); Content length: 12 bytes (12 B)

I thought the HTTP 400 Bad Request using a Kotlin DTO was due to a missing Jackson Kotlin module so I installed and configured it, but it did not help.
My expected result is that it should return HTTP 200 OK in both cases. Why doesn't it do so?
The project is mixed Java and Kotlin. Using Spring Boot.
Since it's a normal HTTP 400 Bad Request, the server logs do not say anyhting.

What do you see in server logs?

For starters ditch your JacksonConfig and remove the version from the jackson-module-kotlin. Spring will detect it and register it, adding your own ObjectMapper disables a large part of the auto-configuration. A data class, afaik, is akin to records and doesn't have a default constructor. You would need to add an @JsonCreator on the data class .

@talexmovedtoCodidact the server logs do not say anything since it's just a 400

@M.Deinum thank you, data class PromptRequest @JsonCreator constructor(val prompt: String) does the trick. I thought this was supported out of the box though, without any additional annotations? I thoght I've read about it being suppored now..

That depends on the Spring (Boot) version in use and what you have for configuration. As you added your own ObjectMapper parts of the auto-configuration will back off. Also that support was added for form binding and IIRC not for JSON serialization as that relies on a 3rd party framework.

@JsonCreator is unnecessary.
In my case, this works just fine:
@Configuration
class ObjectMapperConfig {

    @Bean
    fun makeObjectMapper(): ObjectMapper {
        return JsonMapper.builder()
            .addModule(KotlinModule.Builder().configure(KotlinFeature.StrictNullChecks, true).build())
            .addModule(JavaTimeModule())
            // other custom: .addModule(....)
            .disable(DeserializationFeature.ADJUST_DATES_TO_CONTEXT_TIME_ZONE)
            .disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS)
            .build()
    }
}

